# Discord бот на python не создает базу данных, выходит ошибка 'TypeError: StartCommand.on_ready() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self''

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Дискорд бот не создаёт таблицу в базе данных, создание находится в методе on_ready, сама консоль выдаёт ошибку:

```
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Alexander\Projects\IrisBot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: StartCommand.on_ready() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Вот сам код:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random, logging
import sqlite3

from config import *

logger = logging.getLogger('discord')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(name)s: %(message)s'))
logger.addHandler(handler)

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

connection = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=settings['PREFIX'], intents=intents)


class StartCommand(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @bot.event
    async def on_ready(self):
        logger.info(f'{self.user} has connected to Discord!')

        cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
            name TEXT,
            id INT,
            cash BIGINT,
            rep INT,
            lvl INT,
            server_id INT
        )""")

        for guild in bot.guilds:
            for member in guild.members:
                if cursor.execute(f'SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}').fetchone() is None:
                    cursor.execute(f'INSERT INTO users VALUES ("{member}", {member.id}, 0, 0, 1, {guild.id})')
                else:
                    pass

        cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS shop (
            role_id INT,
            id INT,
            cost BIGINT
        )""")

        connection.commit()
        print('client connected')

    @commands.command(name='говори')
    async def __say(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send('Im ready')


bot.add_cog(StartCommand(bot))
bot.run(settings['TOKEN'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде проблема решена, таблицы создаются. Я решил проблему, добавив перед фукнцией on_ready декоратор @staticmethod:

```
class StartCommand(commands.Cog):
    @staticmethod
    @bot.event
    async def on_ready():
        pass
```